# How to assign a parent reference to an object

Tags: c#, reference

Suppose I have the following objects:

```
ZeroObject A = new ZeroObject("A");
ZeroObject B = new ZeroObject("B");
ZeroObject C = new ZeroObject("C");
ZeroObject D = new ZeroObject("D");
```

When I do:

```
B = A;
```

somewhere in the code, `B` should have a reference of `A`, right?

Then:

```
C = B;
```

that means `C` is reference of `B`.  Is there a way to give `C` the reference of `A` without using:

```
C = A;
```

Comment: Is `ZeroObject` a `class` or a `struct`? Because if it's a `class`, your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: why do you want to do that without using C = A ?

Comment: I got the feeling that you are confused, please check for example [this](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) or google for C# reference vs value types.

Comment: "is there a way to give C the reference of A without using C = A;" ...because you are entering an obfuscated C# contest?

Comment: A practical usage example would be brilliant right now.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm assuming `ZeroObject` is a class. If it's not, please disregard this answer.

> when I do
>
> ```
> B = A;
> ```
>
> somewhere in the code,
>
> ```
> B should have a reference of A, right?
> ```

Well, it means that `B` will have the same value as `A`. Any further changes to the *value of `A`* (e.g. to make it refer to a different object) will have no effect on `A`. If you change the data within the object that both `A` and `B` refer to, however, you'll be able to see that change through either reference.

Read [my article on reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/%7Eskeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more information.

> is there a way to give C the reference of A without using
>
> C = A;
>
> in C#?

Well there are bizarre ways you could do it. For example:

```
public void SetValue<T>(out T target, T value)
{
     target = value;
}

...

SetValue(out C, A);
```

... but it's unclear why you'd *want* to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced inventing some undefined "ZeroObject" is helpful so I'm just going to go ahead and use strings:

```
string A = "A";
string B = "B";
string C = "C";

//Values are now A, B, C

B = A;

//Values are now A, A, C

C = B;

//Values are now A, A, A
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you *exactly* mean, saying " give C the reference".

If this is about "pointing to the **same** memory location", it would be enough to assign them to each other.

So

```
    B = A;
    C = B
```

`C` would point to the same `A` memory space.

But this is kind of *really* strange work way, honestly. Just assign a reference `C=A`.

If this is not what you're searching for, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Is ZeroObject a class of your own?

Programatically, it sounds like you're wanting a referenced object, such as a child object (whatever it may be called in this case).

So, ideally, you want another property on your ZeroObject class, of type ZeroObject - named ReferenceObject (or whatever you prefer), in which you'd assign your sub-object to.

I.e.

```
public class ZeroObject
{
    //Properties
    ZeroObject ReferenceObject { get; set; }
}

ZeroObject A = new ZeroObject("A");
ZeroObject B = new ZeroObject("B");

A.ReferenceObject = B;
```

Then simply access `B` by `A.ReferenceObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ZeroObject` must have a corresponding property

```
public class ZeroObject
{
    public ZeroObject (string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public ZeroObject Parent { get; set }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

now, you can write

```
ZeroObject A = new ZeroObject("A");
ZeroObject B = new ZeroObject("B");
ZeroObject C = new ZeroObject("C");
ZeroObject D = new ZeroObject("D");

B.Parent = A;
C.Parent = B;
D.Parent = C;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want same object without referenced it, check that link and use that basic solution.

[Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp)